# JavaScript uncaught type error illegal invocation

Tags: javascript

```
var Rules = Rules || (function () {

    saverule = function () {
        var level = document.getElementById("level-selection");
            var metrics = document.getElementById("metric-selection");
            var operator = document.getElementById("operator-selection");
            var value = document.getElementById("value123");
            var saveAction = $("#hidden-save").val();
            $.post(saveAction, { level_id: level, product_id: metrics, opp: operator, value: value }, function () {


            },
                'json');
        };
    wireLinkActions = function () {

        $("a.save-ok").on("click", function(event) {
            saverule();
            return false;
        });
    };
    return {
        Initialize: function () {

            wireLinkActions();
        }
    }
})();

$(document).ready(Rules.Initialize);
```

illegal invocation error it wont even cal the the save rule function while debugging also

Comment: I don't think this is `complete` code. Please add complete code

Comment: can you tell us what the error is also you're combining jquery syntaxes and JS intentionally ?

Comment: @Pogrindis jQuery syntax does not exist. jQuery *is* JavaScript. It’s just a library.

Comment: @idmean yes I am aware of that but if the library is not included then using `$("#id").val()` is not going to work.

Comment: Well, `$.on()` won't either, and there's no reason your jquery wouldnt be included if you... do include it ? Also, is the `Initialize()` function fired in `document.ready` ?

Comment: Would be fantastic to get the error from this InB4 `$ not defined`! ^

Comment: yes the initialize function is fired in the document.ready

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion `operator` is causing an issue.. Could you rename this to something else and test?

Comment: i tried changing it it's giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your return the values and not the DOM element itself.
For example change this:

```
var level = document.getElementById("level-selection");
```

into this:

```
var level = document.getElementById("level-selection").value;
```

or, simply use jQuery such as this:

```
var level = $("#level-selection").val();
```